# ranking multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have some numpy arrays like this

```
p1  = np.array([140,142,145])
p2  = np.array([130,144,147])
p3  = np.array([150,141,147])
p4  = np.array([150,141,148])
```

I want to compare the first number in p1 with the first number in p2,p3 and p4, etc.

In this instance I want to find if each element is among the lowest two so that the output is

```
np.array([True,False,True])
np.array([True,False,True])
np.array([False,True,True])
np.array([False,True,False])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`np.argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) to find the smallest 2 values for each column:

```
import numpy as np
p1  = np.array([140,142,145])
p2  = np.array([130,144,147])
p3  = np.array([150,141,147])
p4  = np.array([150,141,148])
P = np.row_stack([p1,p2,p3,p4])

result = np.argpartition(P, 2, axis=0) < 2
print(result)
```

yields

```
[[ True False  True]
 [ True False  True]
 [False  True False]
 [False  True False]]
```

---

`np.argpartition(arr, k)` *partially* sorts `arr` in ascending order. 
Each group of `k` elements is smaller than the next group of `k` elements,
but within each group the elements may not be sorted.

---

Note that the code above always has exactly 2 True values per column.
It finds 2 of the lowest values for each column, but may not find *all* such values.
If you wish to find all such values, you could use

```
In [302]: P <= P[np.argpartition(P, 2, axis=0), np.arange(P.shape[1])][1]
Out[302]: 
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

`P[np.argpartition(P, 2, axis=0), np.arange(P.shape[1])]` returns `P` in column-sorted order.

```
In [5]: P[np.argpartition(P, 2, axis=0), np.arange(P.shape[1])]
Out[5]: 
array([[130, 141, 145],
       [140, 141, 147],
       [150, 142, 147],
       [150, 144, 148]])
```

`P[np.argpartition(P, 2, axis=0), np.arange(P.shape[1])][1]` selects the 2nd row. These are the 2nd lowest values in each column.

```
In [6]: P[np.argpartition(P, 2, axis=0), np.arange(P.shape[1])][1]
Out[6]: array([140, 141, 147])
```

The comparison `P <= np.array([140, 141, 147])` is performed by [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the array on the right-hand side from shape (3,) up to shape (4,3) so the comparison can be done element-wise.